# How to alter query results before loop : wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wonder if it exists wp_query results before loop, as pre_get_posts is to alter before query i need a filter or action to alter the results, please see below :

```
// THe main query
$args = ["post_type" => "product"];
$query = new Wp_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) : 
    while($query->have_posts) : $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

So i need to make a function to play with some fields in woocommerce, too complex or impossible for a sql query (it about to find date availability from official woocommerce booking plugin) so i created following function somewhere :

```
/** 
* this function get post id and remove when it not available on specific date
* @param post_id int, the post id
* @param $date string, the search date
*/
function get_post_availability($post_id, $date) { 
    
 }
```

If i call this function inside above loop, i will break pagination, so how is there something like "after_get_posts" in wordpress?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure, maybe, posts_results will help - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_results/ . Also there is a hook called posts_where_paged - it fires after pagination was set (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where_paged/).

Comment: Hi, interesting, thank you very much